# Can not launch more than one MIDlet in eclipse error?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-me, nokia, midlet

I've been asking questions on here for some time, but this will be my most nooby of all
sadly ¬_¬

I've just downloaded Eclipse Pulsar with a Nokia simulator tied into it. Ran the application as a midlet the first time and it worked, but now when I try to run the application, it comes up with the error:

> Can not launch more than one MIDlet suite at the same time

Thing is, I've searched about the problem, found no solution, but it seems a basic thing however help would be fantastic.

Comment: Which Nokia emulator are you using?

Comment: The one I got in the Symbian_Belle SDK download. That's about all I know on that one.

Comment: My guess is your midlet does not exit on the first run for some reason. How do you exit after the first run during testing?

Comment: That seems to be it. After a reinstall, I can now abort the initial run. At first I was aborting the midlet, and as I said, it seemed to work after a reinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My guess is your midlet does not exit on the first run for some reason. How do you exit after the first run during testing?

That seems to be it. After a reinstall, I can now abort the initial run. At first I was aborting the midget and it was perhaps not doing so, and as I said, it seemed to work after a reinstall.